# Recreate deleted user in windows server 2016

Tags: forms, security, directory, window, profile

How to recreate a deleted local user in weindows server 2016 and use the same home folder that is not deleted
For exemple : I have a local user , his name is chobo
So the home folder is c users chobo
I have accidentally removed the user chobo but the home folder was not deleted
When I have created a new user with the same name  so an other home folder has been created but name of folder was chobo.powevm

Powervm is the name of computer
So how can I do to create a user with the same name and have the old home folder like a home folder in order to see the same files and use the same softs installed by the origin user chobo
?

I have tryed to create a user with the same name without a results